# Error in apply(dat[, batch == batch_level], 1, function(x) { : dim(X) must have a positive length

Tags: combat, sva

I am new here so forgive me if I don't provide all the details in the first go. There is a very similar question ([how to solve “dim(X) must have a positive length” at running ComBat function in R](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/10914/how-to-solve-dimx-must-have-a-positive-length-at-running-combat-function-in)) but the solution did not work for me.

I am getting `Error in apply(dat[, batch == batch_level], 1, function(x) { :    dim(X) must have a positive length` when I use the `sva` library's `comBat()` function.

It works when I use the following:

```
> dim(log_proteins_norm_sorted)
[1] 5415   66

> log_proteins_norm_sorted[1:5,1:5]
      1027     1075     1116     1119    11211
1 22.50513 20.64312 21.56182 22.01455 23.17497
2 21.67946 20.90994 21.61928 21.92025 21.98503
3 21.06812 20.52647 20.72076 20.79732 21.38957
4 18.95485 19.70027 18.39504 20.20218 19.79887
5 22.75966 22.32306 22.32936 22.39271 22.84204

> dim(samples_pheno)
[1] 66 24

> samples_pheno[1:3,1:3]
     Trial Number  Trial Sample
1027      222       A   1027
1075      223       A   1075
1116      224       A   1116

> proteins_combat = ComBat(dat= as.matrix(log_proteins_norm_sorted), batch=samples_pheno$Batch ,  par.prior = T)
Found10batches
Adjusting for0covariate(s) or covariate level(s)
Standardizing Data across genes
Fitting L/S model and finding priors
Finding parametric adjustments
Adjusting the Data
```

So as you can see, this works. However, when I subset some of the samples and reduce the sample number from 66 to 55 and run comBat, I get the following:

```
> dim(log_proteins_MRD_sorted)
[1] 5415   55
> log_proteins_MRD_sorted[1:5,1:5]
      1027     1075     1116     1119     1217
1 22.55492 20.69292 21.61162 22.06435 21.86900
2 21.72926 20.95974 21.66907 21.97005 21.35203
3 21.11791 20.57627 20.77055 20.84712 21.01896
4 19.00465 19.75006 18.44483 20.25198 18.95107
5 22.80946 22.37285 22.37915 22.44250 22.50524

> dim(samples_pheno3)
[1] 55 24
> samples_pheno3[1:3,1:3]
     Trial Number  Trial Sample
1027      222        A   1027
1075      223        A   1075
1116      224        A   1116

> proteins_combat_MRD = ComBat(dat= as.matrix(log_proteins_MRD_sorted), batch=samples_pheno3$Batch ,  par.prior = T)
Error in apply(dat[, batch == batch_level], 1, function(x) { : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

In case you wanted to know, I am working with the same original file for `log_proteins_MRD_sorted` and `log_proteins_norm_sorted`. I just removed the 11 samples from the 66 samples and then normalised the data again (hence slight difference in values between the two objects.

For `samples_pheno3`, I run this code:

```
> #Subset the phenotype data to those samples with only MRD data
> samples_pheno2 <- samples_pheno[-c(5,6,11,16,21, 26, 29,30,32, 45,56),]
> MRD_NA1 <- rownames(samples_pheno2)[!is.na(samples_pheno2$MRD)]
> samples_pheno3 <- samples_pheno2[MRD_NA1,]
```

Also this is out my data looks like for the batches:

```
> samples_pheno3$Batch
 [1] 7  5  6  9  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  10 10 10 10 11 11 11 2  7  2  2  2  9  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  7 
[38] 10 3  4  10 4  4  8  4  4  4  5  5  5  8  11 5  5  5 
Levels: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

So just by subsetting the data to 55 samples, it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Is it the way I am subsetting the data which is confusing the code?

I would be grateful for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of my very capable local bioinformatician, I have found a solution. Essentially, the problem was that when I reduced the sample size from 66 to 55, there was a batch number which only had 1 sample in it. When I removed that sample from the analysis, and ensured that each batch had at least 2 samples in it, the `ComBat()` then worked nicely!

Hope this helps future googlers.